# How to use python script from Node.js?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, child-process

I have a Node.js - Express API where I want to use one endpoint to invoke a Python script. I've bee trying to do this with child process but struggling with how to pass a file from post request body to the script. So, basically what I want to do is retrieve a file attached to a post request and pass it to a Python function. How can this be done?

Comment: I am not 100% confident on Node.js syntax wise, but have you tried this

1. Accept file from post request on node
2. Call python script from express route and pass the file object to the python script(ensure that the python script is able to take command line arguments)

Answer (score 0):

You can use child_process to execute any command

eg.

```
const child_process = require("child_process");
const cmd = "python -v";
const child = child_process.spawn(cmd);

      child.on("error", function (err) {
        console.log(data.toString("utf8"));
      });

      child.stdout.on("data", function (data) {
        console.log(data.toString("utf8"));
      });

      child.stderr.on("data", function (data) {
        console.log(data.toString("utf8"));
      });
```

Comment: So to clarify this to myself, if I have file.zip which I send as an attachment of POST REQUEST body to my Node.js API, which uses child process to invoke pyscript.py. How do I get that file.zip in the python script so I can use it there?